# printing multidimensional vector in rows , cols and depth order

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, printing

I am trying to print 3D array of vectors in order of rows x cols x depth, but getting something different. e.g. I want to print a **3x2x5** array of vectors, the output of my code is :

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

The output is like: 2(rows) x 5(cols) x 3, it look wrong to me.

Here is my code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const int N = 3;
const int M = 2;
const int Q = 5;

typedef std::vector<double> dim1;
typedef std::vector<dim1> array2D;
typedef std::vector<array2D> array3D;

array2D A(N, dim1(M));
array2D B(N, dim1(M));
array3D C(N, array2D(M, dim1(Q)));

int main() {

    for (int ix = 0; ix < N; ++ix) {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < M; ++iy) {
            for (int iq = 0; iq < Q; ++iq) {
                C[ix][iy][iq] = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int ix = 0; ix < N; ++ix) {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < M; ++iy) {
            for (int iq = 0; iq < Q; ++iq) {
                std::cout << C[ix][iy][iq];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost working. The only thing that I see that is missing from your code is a space between the numbers in a row.

```
std::cout << C[ix][iy][iq] << " ";
                           ^^^^^^
```

That would add a space even after the last number of the row. If that is not acceptable, you'll need a bit of additional logic:

```
for (int iq = 0; iq < Q; ++iq) {
    std::cout << C[ix][iy][iq];
    if ( iq < Q-1 ) {
       std::cout << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added std::endl..will it not work the same way as space?

Comment: @TheCoder `std::endl` will give you a line return.

Comment: I would like to write a function that will pass **Vectors A & B** and return a 1-dimensional vector. I don't know how to write. Any help is appreciated.